# Magento 2: Page template is coming blank

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, home-page

I created a theme in magento 2 and in that theme i created a new page layout.

I can see the page layout in my magento admin dashboard.

So i assigned the page layout to my homepage.

But now my home page is coming blank.

[image: My theme structure:]

My theme Code

***Registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Magento/DrugTheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

***Theme.xml***

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Magestore Simple Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

**layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd" layout="1column">
    <layout id="test">
        <label translate="true">Full Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

And finally my 
***test.xml*** (My page layout file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
   <update handle="2columns-left"/>
   <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
       <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   <referenceContainer name="columns">
       <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
   </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some other vendor name in `registration.php`

```
'frontend/Vendor/DrugTheme'
```

Create a `composer.json` like -

```
{
 "name": "magento/theme-frontend-yourtheme", //declare your theme
 "description": "N/A",
 "require": {
 "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
 "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.0.*", //blank is my parent theme here
 "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
 },
 "type": "magento2-theme",
 "version": "100.0.5",
 "license": [
 "OSL-3.0",
 "AFL-3.0"
 ],
 "autoload": {
 "files": [
 "registration.php"
 ]
 }
}
```

I am not sure there is any `layouts.xml`

You should add `default.xml` and `default_head_blocks.xml` in `Magento_Theme/layout`

Your ideal structure should be like -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

> Edit-

For custom layout try creating a module, and place the layouts.xml and test.xml in there.

Check link - https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-layout-page/

Comment: Tried ,still not working

Comment: It will be great if you can share the complete directory structure, what you tried and what is not working.

Comment: My themes public repo :
https://github.com/akshaynaiksjinnovation/Theme

Comment: I have update my answer, with new reference link. You can try creating a module and add layout to that like reference link.